# How to custom the table name in peewee?

Tags: postgresql, peewee

I want to define a table which the table name is gobang_server,i write code as follow:

```
class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = database

class GobangServer(BaseModel):
    time = DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    name = CharField(max_length=64)
    host = CharField(max_length=30)
    port = IntegerField()
    pid = IntegerField()
```

but i look at PostgreSQL the table name is "gobangserver"?
How can i define with the table name is gobang_server and the class name is not be modified.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
class GobangServer(BaseModel):
    ...
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'gobang_server'
```

In peewee 3.0 it changes from "db_table" to "table_name".